# Rally rest recyclebin

Tags: java, api, rest, rally, recycle-bin

In the Rally REST Java API (1.40), how can I create a QueryRequest to find a specific DELETED item by FormattedID.

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("recyclebinentry");
```

I see in an unrestricted query ( e.g. no filter set ), the value for the FormattedID is returned in the "ID" property, but using that property or FormattedID in a query results in the queryResponse.wasSuccessful() being false.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Recycle Bin offers only very limited query-ability. As you've found, FormattedID is not accepted, nor are DeletedBy, Name, Type, or other useful identifying fields. The best you can really do is filter by DeletionDate. For example `(DeletionDate >= "2013-03-01T15:00:00Z")` to narrow your results. Then manually search on the client-side.

I'd recommend posting this as a Feature Request to [Rally Ideas](https://ideas.rallydev.com), since this is a commonly requested item.